# is there a way to get the code lines for a PHP ReflectionProperty?

Tags: php, reflection

PHP's ReflectionFunction has methods that tell you what line it starts and ends on, so you can with a bit of string manipulation load the code file and get its source code.

ReflectionProperty does not have any similar methods. It has a __string() magic method, but that doesn't return source code.

Is there any way to get the source code for a class property?

Comment: Idea: Get the class, use ReflectionClass, try to parse it?

Comment: You want to get the exact original source code? Otherwise, ReflectionProperty contains all methods to recreate it (including doc comment).

Comment: Yes, it's the original code I want. The property has an array value split over several lines, and each line has a comment line - it's those that I want to get.